# How to move, resize and return to original position a subview present in the main view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, calayer

In some of the applications, I have seen that we can drag a view outside of its position using two fingers(in smooth motion). We are also able to resize, rotate and move it further. And when I take my fingers off the screen it just resized(also rotates) and go backs to its original position by itself in a smooth motion.

How can I do this kind of animation? Is there any sample available? OR just telling me how the flow actually is will also be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIViews are animatable simply by setting properties.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 200);
    myView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
}];
```

Look up animateWithDuration in the docs for more options and examples.

Comment: I have been looking for some time and I am sure that they are using CALayers to do this kinda stuff. I rotate the view by 180 degrees and enlarge it and move it from its original position and leaves it. It on it's way back in a smooth way, resizes, counter rotates and goes and fits back in it's original position. :-o

Comment: Added an example for rotation. The question you need to ask yourself is "how do I rotate something", then the animation comes automatically by wrapping it in an animation block.